# ¿Cómo convertir un número o grupo de números en una cadena a texto en Java?

Tags: java

Si tengo el siguiente código de Java para convertir los números que se encuentren embebidos en una cadena, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que sólo se conviertan los que señalo por medio de una coordenada?

Por ejemplo, si tengo la cadena:

> Esta es una prueba745 de te34xto y núme45ro5s

Esta cadena tiene un `lenght()` de `44`. Si utilizo dos coordenadas para cambiar solamente las posiciones `18`, que sería `‘745’`, y `27`, que sería `‘34’` a texto respectivamente, ¿cómo lo logro sin cambiar todos los números a texto sino solamente aquellos señalados por las coordenadas (posiciones)?

```
public void ConvertirNumerosEnTexto(int startPosition, int endPosition) {
    String[] array = {"Cero", "Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Cuatro", "Cinco", "Seis", "Siete", "Ocho", "Nueve"};

    String _inputString = "Esta es una prueba745 de te34xto y núme45ro5s";

    StringBuilder _builder2 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int h = 0; h < _inputString.length(); h++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(_inputString.charAt(h))) {
            _builder2.append(array[Character.digit(_inputString.charAt(h), 10)]);
        } else { 

            _builder2.append(_inputString.charAt(h));
        }
    }

    String _outputString = _builder2.toString();
    System.out.println(_outputString);
}
```

Salida actual:

> Esta es una pruebaSieteCuatroCinco de teTresCuatroxto y
>   númeCuatroCincoroCinco

Salida deseada:

> Esta es una pruebaSieteCuatroCinco de teTresCuatroxto y núme45ro5s

He intendato usando algo como esto:

```
if (Character.toString(inputText.charAt(startPosition)).equals("0")) {
         numString = inputText.replace(Character.toString(inputText.charAt(startPosition)), zero);
       }
```

Pero, solamente funciona para cambiar un número en la cadena, o dos si se utilizan dos coordenadas, por ejemplo:

> Esta es una pruebaSiete45 de teTress4xto y núme45ro5s

Las coordenadas, en este caso, se pasan por medio de un objeto que pasa los parámetros a la función que convierte los números: `MiCadena.ConvertirNumerosEnTexto(5, 10);`

Comment: y como defines las coordenadas?

Comment: En este caso, las paso por medio de un objeto que pasa los parámetros a la función que convierte los números: MiCadena.ConvertirNumerosEnTexto(5, 10);

Comment: He estado modificando el código. En esta versión no he implementado las posiciones porque en eso es que está basada mi pregunta, pero como mencioné al final, la primera versión sólo lo hace a dos números.

Comment: tu código es correcto solo debes realizar la validación entre que posiciones realizar el reemplazo, agregué un método, saludos.

Comment: Ya me di cuenta. Gracias. Solamente faltaba lo que agregaste. Funciona. Era lo que buscaba. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente saludos! @Mr.Munoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente agrega una condición donde el texto a cambiar se realice unicamente cuando sea mayor  a la posición inicial y menor a la posición final,

```
 if (Character.isDigit(_inputString.charAt(h))   && (h >= posicionA) && (h <= posicionB) ) {
```

por ejemplo usando el código que mueprivate static String

```
convertirNumerosEnTexto(int posicionA, int posicionB)    {

             String[] array = {"Cero", "Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Cuatro", "Cinco", "Seis", "Siete", "Ocho", "Nueve"};

    String _inputString = "Esta es una prueba745 de te34xto y núme45ro5s";

    StringBuilder _builder2 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int h = 0; h < _inputString.length(); h++) {
        //*validación.
        if (Character.isDigit(_inputString.charAt(h)) && (h >= posicionA) && (h <= posicionB) ) { 
            _builder2.append(array[Character.digit(_inputString.charAt(h), 10)]);
        } else { 

            _builder2.append(_inputString.charAt(h));
        }
    }

   String _outputString = _builder2.toString();
   System.out.println(_outputString);
   return  _outputString;
}
```

llamando el método :

```
System.out.println(convertirNumerosEnTexto(18, 34));
```

se obtiene como salida:

```
Esta es una pruebaSieteCuatroCinco de teTresCuatroxto y núme45ro5s
```

ya que solo realiza el reemplazo entre la posición 18 y 34 de la cadena original.